# Как проверить строку на наличие цифр

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, есть следующий фрагмент кода

```
function( itemElem ) {
    var price = $( itemElem ).find('.price').text();
    return parseInt( price.replace( /\D/g, '') );
}
```

Как я понимаю он присваивает переменной `price` значение цифр из строки. Потом эта информация используется для сортировки `<div>` и работает прекрасно. Но задача осложняется тем, что иногда строка содержит только текст без цифр.

(Это строчка цены и встречаются значения "не указано" и "на ваше усмотрение")

Хочу вставить условие, на проверку строки на наличие цифр. Подскажите, как лучше сделать?

Comment: "Как я понимаю он присваивает переменной price значение цифр из строки." - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: `/\d/.test(price)` вернет _true_ если в строке есть хотя бы одна цифра

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, регулярное выражение, проверяющее наличие цифр в строке имеет вид:

```
/[0-9]/.test('a string that should be tested');
```

Однако, в данном случае, вместо явной проверки на наличие цифр, я бы скорее возвращал некоторое "значение по-умолчанию" из функции. Например вот так:

```
function(itemElem) {
    var price = $(itemElem).find('.price').text();

    // Возвращаем 0 если строка не содержит цифр.
    return parseInt(price.replace( /\D/g, '')) || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать метод `search`.

Например

```
if ( price.search(/\d/) != -1 ) { /*...*/ }
```

Так как `search` возвращает позицию первой найденной цифры, то вы можете этим воспользоваться для извлечения числа без использования вашего регулярного выражения.

Comment: в таком случае, если в переменной price будет тип string и не будет найдено чисел, то выскочит ошибка о том что search не является функцией.